# Setting up a static IP for my wireless interface on Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, wireless, static-ip

I am trying to configure my wireless interface to use a static IPv4 address and I suddenly lost connection to the internet.

This is my configuration file content:

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  wifis:
    wlp2s0:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      access-points:
        "bssid": "mybssid"
         password: "mypassword"
      addresses:
        - 192.168.1.100/24
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.1.254
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.8.0]
```

And then when I run "sudo netplan apply"

I get this:

```
/etc/netplan/00-installer-config-wifi.yaml:11:10: Invalid YAML: inconsistent indentation:
         password: "mypassword"
         ^
```

In the fields bssid and password, I entered my Wi-Fi's SSID and Password, and replaced them on this post only for mybssid and mypassword, I don't know if that's correct.

Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: You have multiple mistakes ... See example: https://netplan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/#how-to-connect-to-a-wpa-personal-wireless-network-without-dhcp

Comment: Also see: `cat /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/wireless.yaml`  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Alright thank you guys I solved it. <3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed 00-installer-config-wifi.yaml file:

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  wifis:
    wlp2s0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      access-points:
        "my-bssid":
         password: "my-pass"
      addresses: [192.168.1.100/24]
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.1.254
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.1.254, 8.8.8.8]
```

If anyone is reading this, just replace "my-bssid" with your Wi-Fi SSID and "my-pass" with your Wi-Fi password, and 192.168.1.254 with your default gateway address.

Thank you all.

Comment: you should accept this answer to remove it from questions with un-accepted answers